# Excel vba hangs when extracting PDFs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract 589 pdf files from a zip files to a destination folder. Everyday, zip file is downloaded from a website and destination folder is also created everyday. So, I made the "FromFolder" and "ToFolder" a variable that will be coming from a textboxes.

I have this code from https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/68041-extract-zip-files-without-winzip, but I edited the FromFolder and ToFolder to make it a variable.

Upon trying, only one PDF is extracted and the excel hangs.

Does anyone know any workaround for this code? I'm not sure where the problem is. Thanks a lot!

```
 Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Sub ExtractPDF_Click()
        Call Copy_Files(FromFolder:=tbPDFpath.Value, ToFolder:=tbDestination.Value, FolderItself:=False)
    End Sub


Sub Copy_Files(FromFolder As String, ToFolder As String, _
                    Optional FolderItself As Boolean = False, _
                    Optional ErrorFound As Boolean = False)

Const LoopWait As Long = 1, EndWait As Long = 5 'seconds
Dim FromFolderVar As Variant, ToFolderVar As Variant
Dim ShellApp As Object
Dim ItemCount As Long, AdditionalCount As Long

On Error GoTo EndSub
ErrorFound = False: Err.Clear

FromFolderVar = CVar(FromFolder)
ToFolderVar = CVar(ToFolder)
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

With ShellApp

    ItemCount = .Namespace(ToFolderVar).Items.Count

    If FolderItself Then
        AdditionalCount = 1
        .Namespace(ToFolderVar).CopyHere .Namespace(FromFolderVar)
    Else
        AdditionalCount = .Namespace(FromFolderVar).Items.Count
        .Namespace(ToFolderVar).CopyHere .Namespace(FromFolderVar).Items
    End If

    On Error Resume Next 'need to it error skip if it hasn't finished setting up the folder, and so can't 'read' its contents
        Do Until .Namespace(ToFolderVar).Items.Count = ItemCount + AdditionalCount
            Sleep LoopWait * 1000 'Keep script waiting until copying / compressing is done
        Loop
    On Error GoTo EndSub

End With

Sleep EndWait * 1000 'insert a pause at the end to be on the safe side
Set ShellApp = Nothing

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you have seems to copy 1 folder or all files (depending on the value of `FolderItself`). Have you checked that your zip file mirrors this expected structure? I would remove the last `on error resume next` from around the Do loop where you perform the `items.count` comparison. Put it before a new Do loop, in which you test for a condition like `.namespace(tofoldervar).items is not nothing` and when the condition evaluates to true, use `on error goto 0` to clear the error state -- and only then proceed with the Do loop (with items.count comparison).

Comment: That way, you're restricting the sections of your code that are suppressing errors. Also, you may want to put in a `DoEvents` in the final DoLoop to keep the OS responsive, as 598 files may take a while to copy (I assume you have 598 PDFs inside a single zip folder).

Comment: Might also want to get rid of that initial `on error goto EndSub` for the same reason.